# XSLT : getting the prefix of an element?

Tags: xml, xslt, function, prefix

In XSLT 1.0, you can get the local name  or the namespaceUri of an XML element using the functions:

```
string local-name (node)
```

and

```
string namespace-uri(node)
```

but is there a standard **function** to get the **prefix** of an element having a qualified name ?

Comment: I'm curious about why you would want the prefix? at the end of the day the xslt engine doesn't really 'understand' prefixes but rather namespaces, the output document, for example, may well use a different prefix for the same namespace? (either may also have different prefixes applied to the same namespace...)

Comment: @Yossi I want to generate a Java stub for a StaX Parser ( http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html ) from a XML file. This API requires to declare the namespaces and to give a prefix to the qNames.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as far as I know. If you're sure the node name has a prefix, you can use this:

```
substring-before(name(), ':')
```

or this, if you are not sure:

```
substring-before(
  name(), 
  concat(':', local-name())
)
```

The latter expression is based on the fact that `substring-before()` returns the empty string when the searched string is not found. This way it will work correctly for prefixed *and* unprefixed names.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if you care about an element's prefix, you're doing it wrong.  You should only care about what namespace it belongs to.

In your comment, you note that the API you're talking to requires you to provide a namespace and a namespace prefix.  That's true, but the API you linked to doesn't actually care what the namespace prefix is - in fact, it will generate a namespace prefix randomly if you don't provide one.

If you're generating entire XML documents, it's nice if you have a one-to-one mapping of prefixes to namespace URIs; it makes the output easier to understand.  But it really doesn't matter what those prefixes are.

Answer (score 1):

For further nuances, I recommend reading ["Perils of the name() function"](http://stage.lenzconsulting.com/namespaces-in-xslt/#perils_of_the_name_function).

For example, only in XPath 2.0 can you reliably get the prefix of an element. In XPath 1.0, the prefix used by an element is not part of the data model.

Given the following XML:

```
<my:foo xmlns:my="http://example.com" xmlns:my2="http://example.com"/>
```

The name() function in XPath 1.0 could legally return either "my:foo" or "my2:foo". But in XPath 2.0, it *must* return "my:foo".

Answer (score -1):

<xsl:value-of select="root()/xs:schema/namespace::node()[.= parent::*/@targetNamespace]/name()"/>

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.